# Obtaining ToolTip name

Tags: winforms, tooltip

I must be stupid, but

```
    ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
    // tooltip.Name << not exists, lol
```

I need it for something like this:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
        this.toolTip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
        ...
    }

    private void SomeMethodOfForm()
    {
        SomeMethodOfClassA(components);
    }
}

public class A
{
    public static SomeMethodOfClassA(IContainer container)
    {
        foreach (Component component in container.Components)
            if (component is ToolTip)
                MessageBox.Show("Found ToolTip"); // want to show here "toolTip1" or "toolTip2"
    }
}
```

What do I do? Designer shows `ToolTip.Name` somehow. How?

Comment: I can use `Tag`, but kek..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, you do realize that each tooltip control can contain the tooltips for Multiple controls?

Comment: Yes, but I want to get its name, because there can be dozens of tooltips (in multiply forms and even in same form!).

Comment: Same thing valid for `ListViewColumn`, I am already using `Tag` there to "transfer name" of it from designer to some other class by using form instance and recursive iteration of controls. Thought if somone knows a solution (idea) here, then I could also implement it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Tag` or any additional custom property seems like the only solution to achieve this.